# OS X , how to merge bulk csv files into an excel worksheet?

Tags: macos, excel, terminal, vba

OS X ,I have 50000 csv files in a folder. How to merge a specified range of all these csv files into a excel worksheet ?

ps. All of these csv files are in the same form. Each of them has two columns. What I want is the middle part of the second column, B45: B145. And in the new excel worksheet，I want the data from each csv file pasted next to each other. The result is in one worksheet.

Thanks for the following suggestions. I have found a solution to this problem.

`find . -name \*.csv -print0 | xargs -0 -L 256 awk -F, 'FNR>=45 && FNR<=145{print $2}' > BigBoy.csv`

Comment: This is a horrendously broad question that could use some additional info.  For example, are each of these 50,000 files the same kind of table (same number of columns?), or do you want the 50,000 files all merged into the Excel worksheet as different tabs/pages?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann thanks. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following command with a single CSV file to see if it extracts the fields you want:

```
awk -F, 'FNR>=45 && FNR<=145{print $2}'   AnySingleFile.csv
```

It prints the second field (`$2`) of all lines with line number greater than or equal 45 and less than or equal 145. The `-F,` sets the field separator to a comma.

If that works, the next command to try would be this, but I doubt it will work with 50,000 files:

```
awk -F, 'FNR>=45 && FNR<=145{print $2}' *.csv   > BigBoy.csv
```

So, I would suggest you use `find` and `xargs` to process, say 256 files, at a time:

```
find . -name \*.csv -print0 | xargs -0 -L 256 awk -F, 'FNR>=45 && FNR<=145{print $2}' > BigBoy.csv
```

That command works like this...*'Find all files ending in `.csv` and print their names separated with nul characters passing that list to `xargs`. It will then split the list and pass 256 files at a time to `awk` which will do exactly what the initial `awk` did."*

The idea of passing 256 files to `awk` is to save having to execute a new process for every single one of your 50,000 CSV files. You may get away with a bigger number, depending on the length of your filenames. See Note at end.

Your results should be in `BigBoy.csv`.

**Note 1:** If your CSV files have many hundreds of lines, you will get a performance increase if you change the `awk` code to:

'FNR>=45 && FNR<=145{print $2} FNR==145{exit}'

**Note 2:** The limit (in characters) for the length of the arguments passed to `awk` (and any other program) can be found with:

```
sysctl kern.argmax
```

and on OSX, it is 262,144 characters. So if your CSV filenames are 8-10 characters long on average, you could probably pass over 26,000 filenames. If they are 260 characters long on average, you should not pass more than around 1,000 filenames.

Comment: Yes, `awk -F, 'FNR>=45 && FNR<=145{print $2}' *.csv   > BigBoy.csv` doesn't work with 50000 files. But  `find . -name \*.csv -print0 | xargs -0 -L 256 awk -F, 'FNR>=45 && FNR<=145{print $2}' > BigBoy.csv`  perfectly solved my question. Thanks for suggestion.